# getwchar() requiring a keypress after enter before exiting from while loop

Tags: c, windows, getchar

I'm writing a parser which needs to read user input as they type. I'm in Windows so I'm using putwchar and getwchar. I have used SetConsoleMode to disable "ENABLE_LINE_INPUT" and "ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT" so I can just grab each character.

This is the relevant code:

```
do {
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(CONSOLE_INPUT);
    wcs_buffer = getwchar();
    switch (wcs_buffer){

    case L'\r':
        listening = 0;
        break;

    default:
        putwchar(wcs_buffer);
        break;
    }
} while (listening);
```

I would expect the return key (which I believe is \r?) to immediately exit the while loop but it doesn't, a key needs to be inputted after return before anything happens.

What's causing this behaviour and can I do anything to prevent it?

Comment: try \n or \r\n it should do it

Comment: Neither \n or \r\n fix it. \n doesn't react to enter and \r\n just exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by anything happens? What do you expect to happen? Are you using a debugger?

Comment: There's more code than this, I only posted the relevant excerpt which might have been mistake. I expect to be able to enter characters until I press enter at which point the while loop should be exited and the next part of my code should execute. What happens instead is I press enter and nothing will happen until another key is pressed, and then it breaks the while loop as it should have. I'm using Visual Studio's debugger but I'm pretty unskilled at it.

Comment: Why are you using FlushConsoleInputBuffer? I don't think it's necessary here.

Comment: Try _getwch - it is not C/C++ standard, but can be used in Windows.

Comment: @o_weisman I don't know, it's probably not I was just experimenting with stuff.

Comment: @AlexFarber _getwch doesn't seem to be recognized?

Comment: What is the type of `wcs_buffer`? Is it `wint_t` type.

Comment: @askmish No, it's wchar_t

Comment: it should be `wint_t` type, because `getwchar()` returns in `wint_t`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/getwchar/

Comment: Ah right, I've changed it. Still doesn't fix my issue though.

Comment: can you check if `iswspace()` detects your enter key. It would also detect spaces, so you may have to write a separate `case` to ignore spaces.

Comment: I've set it to print something every time iswspace detects a space, just to see if it does detect the enter. It still exhibits the same behaviour: I press enter and nothing happens until I press another key. As soon as I press the other key, however, it iswspace detects something. It seems that enter is being intercepted by something else like the Windows console but it really shouldn't be since I'm pretty sure I've got all the relevant flags disabled...